# Just installed Ubuntu 13.10 and I am seeing higher CPU usage than expected

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, ubuntu-13.10

I recently installed the latest version of Ubuntu.  It runs great but there is one problem.  Very high CPU loads.  When I have chrome open, the computer is commonly running at about 50% load.  When streaming videos, the CPU can hike up to 100% mark.  The highest CPU users according to the `top` command are `Xorg` and `compiz`, which I know are UI apps.  Chrome only takes around 10% usually and the rest is the UI.

What can I do to fix this?  I followed the High CPU Troubleshooting Page on Ubuntu website but it didn't help.  GPU is working fine, etc.  I have an A10 3600M CPU.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, xorg is the windowing system, and compiz is a layer ontop of the server which allows for 3D effects.

The high CPU usage is likely indicative of software rendering instead of hardware rendering.

As mentioned [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369033/compiz-using-40-cpu-on-ubuntu-13-10), you can run `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` to see if software rendering is being used.  If so, you'll see something like:

```
Not software rendered:    no
```

I'm not familiar enough with where the AMD APU support is these days with regards to 3D drivers, but I'd check the additional drivers and see if there's any updates for `fglrx` or `fglrx-updates`, which should then enable hardware rendering, and reduce the CPU load.

If you want more of a boost, disabling some of the visual effects could help.  CCSM can help with that:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
```

After installing, you can just search for CCSM, and that'll let you disable some of the visual effects, which may help you get performance back.

Comment: When I ran the thing for software rendering, it returned a yes.  I'm assuming that means it is using the GPU.  When I installed 13.10, it was my first Linux install.  I didn't install any special drivers for the graphics.  Do you need to install a certain graphics driver?  I went to AMD's website and followed their wizard.  I have just started downloading it as we speak.  Thanks for the help.